# Matplotlib Issues in venv

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have encountered an issue I've never really had before. I am pretty familiar with matplotlib and making figure objects, axes and all that. However, when I try to run this EXTREMELY simple code in matplotlib...

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x = np.arange(0,21)
y = x
plt.plot(x,y)
plt.show()
```

I get the following error...

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
Input In [7], in <module>
      1 plt.plot(x,y)
----> 2 plt.show()

AttributeError: 'AxesSubplot' object has no attribute 'show'
```

I cannot understand why I am getting this attribute error. I do not think this is a code issue, as this is the simplest possible matplotlib code that we could write (this should return a line of slope 1 in a range of 1 to 20, basically the 'hello world' of matplotlib). Does anyone have insight into why I'm getting this error?

I suspect that this is a package issue. This is my first time using matplotlib in a python venv, as opposed to a conda virtual environment. When I pip install matplotlib, I feel like I may be missing a package that supports the .show() method. I never had an issue using matplotlib on the conda environment because I installed it through the anaconda navigator. I trust that the pip install would take care of any package dependencies, but I'm not sure. If anyone has insight it would be much appreciated.

Comment: That's very strange. That ought to work. Could you have somehow assigned the return value of `plt.plot()` to plt? Does restarting the kernel help?

Comment: @NickODell Funny enough, you had it. This was actually a snippet of code I wrote to test in an old jupyter notebook, and for some reason, in that notebook, I had an unfortunately-named variable "plt". This was the classic "crappy variable name biting you in the rear end months later". I am contemplating deleting this question because it's not insightful at all, but I really appreciate you taking time to answer it.

Comment: Hah, no worries! Glad to have been able to help.